# How do I differentiate objects in python on canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, grid

I want to press any square on this grid and I want for it to turn yellow. But I can only make the most recent block created yellow with itemconfig. What do I do?

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

canv = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
canv.pack()

def select(event):
    print("Coordinates:", event.x, ",",event.y)
    canv.itemconfig(grid,fill="yellow")

y=1
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(0,10):
        grid=canv.create_rectangle(1+(20*j),y,20+(20*j),20+y,fill="red")
        canv.tag_bind(grid,'<Button-1>',select)
    y+=20


mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I came to this solution:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

canv = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
canv.pack()

def select(event, grid):
    print("Coordinates:", event.x, ",",event.y)
    canv.itemconfig(grid,fill="yellow")

y=1
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(0,10):
        grid=canv.create_rectangle(1+(20*j),y,20+(20*j),20+y,fill="red")
        canv.tag_bind(grid, '<Button-1>', lambda event, var=grid: select(event, var))
    y+=20

mainloop()
```